# Fast access to lines in huge text file

Tags: dataset, information-retrieval, data-retrieval, large-data

I am working with a relatively large text file (70GB uncompressed, 15GB gzipped) which contains 3 columns. The lines of the file are of the form:

```
x1 | y1 | a1
x1 | y2 | a2
x2 | y3 | a3
x3 | y4 | a4
```

The x and y are sequences of words that can contain between 1 and 4 words. The strings in the first column are sorted and not unique. The strings in the second column are not unique, and sorted for a same element in the first column.

There are about 700,000,000 lines in the uncompressed text file, and what I want to do is, for a query of tuples (x, y), get the value a in the third column. I need to access it in a time as short as possible.

What I tried to do to create 2 Dictionaries of (strings, List of integers), so that the first dictionary maps a string to the index of the lines that contain this string in the first column, and the same for the second dictionary and the second column. Then for a query (x, y) I can intersect these two lists and get the line that contains "x | y | a". I can then use a dictionary that maps a line number to its offset in the file and use random access file to read the line.

The problem is that this requires way too much memory (maybe it's also because I'm using Java!). I am looking for a solution that can query the text file very quickly, but doesn't require more than 20 / 30 GB of ram.

I guess there are methods to do this kind of things but I'm not familiar with them. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: sort file, then read about `divide and conquer`

Comment: For some x there are millions of lines with x in the first column, so it would be too slow.

Comment: This is already sorted by x and y. But then what? For a given x should I directly access to the first line that contains it? There are about 30,000,000 different x, so it would require having a huge index for the first column. And then I would have to make the same for the second column... And this requires to work with the uncompressed file. I'm not sure I see how I could use divide and conquer here (to sort the file maybe..)

Comment: Can you not read this file into a SQL DB? You wouldn't have any access problems at all if you were to take this approach.

Comment: I tried with a DB and it's working pretty fast, thanks!